# Error when moving objects between NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

In my iOS app, I have a table view and it has 2 sections/ 2 arrays. I am trying to move an object from one array/section to another array/section. Now Section 0 is called followedArray and Section 1 is called dataArray, dataArray stores all my data that make up each cell. So when the user clicks the button that I have set up called Follow, it's supposed to take that cell and remove it from dataArray/ Section 1 and insert it in followedArray/ Section 0. But when I try to do this I get an error that saids this.

**Error Message**

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3599.6/UITableView.m:1396
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'

**Code:**

**TableView**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    
    // Configuring the cell
    Data * dataObject;
    if (!isFiltered) {
        
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            dataObject = [followedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            dataObject = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }
    else {
        dataObject = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    
    // Loading Button
    cell.followButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.followButton addTarget:self action:@selector(followButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.followButton.hidden = NO;
    
    return cell;
}
```

**Section Headers**

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"Followed Data";
    }
    else {
        return @"All Data";
    }
}
```

**Number of Rows**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    if (!isFiltered) {
        
        if (section == 0) {
            return [followedArray count];
        }
        else if (section == 1) {
            return [dataArray count];
        }
    }
    return [filteredArray count];
}
```

**-----------------------------------------------------**

***-- This is where the action happens --***

**-----------------------------------------------------**

**Follow Button**

```
-(void)followButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    
    // Adding row to tag
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.myTableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    
    // Creating an action per tag
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Current Row = %@", indexPath);
        
        
        // ----- ERROR HERE -----
    [self.myTableView beginUpdates];
    
    // ----- Inserting Cell to Section 0 ----- *NOT WORKING*
    [followedArray insertObject:[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] atIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger rowToAdd = indexPath.row;
    [self.myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToAdd inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:YES];
    
    // ----- Removing Cell from Section 1 ----- *WORKING*
    [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger rowToRemove = indexPath.row;
    [self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToRemove inSection:1], nil] withRowAnimation:YES];
    
    [self.myTableView endUpdates];
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove beginUpdates and  endUpdates. Try now!

Comment: @Manigandasaravanan same error

Comment: // Adding row to tag
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.myTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

Why you doing this for IndexPath ??

Comment: @Dhanesh thats for the button I have in each cell to give me a different tag, why, is it causing a conflict?

Comment: yes its giving you wrong IndexPath May be thats why its creating problem.

Comment: NSLog(@"Current Row = %@", indexPath); What you are getting here?

Comment: [followedArray insertObject:indexPath atIndex:indexPath.row]; Did you tell what kind of data you enter in followedarray

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya It looks like I didn't, what should I put?

Comment: just now for testing just pass simple data that you have in followedArray dont pass now indexpath and tell just after adding your array just print it and tell me is there your current array adding some value or not ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I have no data in followedArray, its currently empty and waiting for something to be transferred

Comment: @BroSimple did you update your answer with one screen that shows your tableview ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I didn't, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126491/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-brosimple).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what helped me fix the errors, Credits to @AliOmari , @Rachel & @CodeChanger

```
    [self.myTableView beginUpdates];

    [followedArray insertObject:[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] atIndex:0];
    [myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger rowToRemove = indexPath.row;
    [self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToRemove inSection:1], nil] withRowAnimation:YES];

    [self.myTableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify Follow Button Code as mention below:

**Follow Button**

```
-(void)followButtonClick:(UIButton*)sender {
    //Use this IndexPath
    NSInteger buttonTag = [sender tag];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:buttonTag inSection:<YourSection>];

    // Creating an action per tag
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Current Row = %@", indexPath);


        // ----- ERROR HERE -----

        [self.myTableView beginUpdates];

        // ----- Inserting Cell to Section 0 -----
        [followedArray insertObject:[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] atIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSInteger rowToAdd = indexPath.row;
        [self.myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToAdd inSection:0], nil] withRowAnimation:YES];

        // ----- Removing Cell from Section 1 -----
        [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSInteger rowToRemove = indexPath.row;
        [self.myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToRemove inSection:1], nil] withRowAnimation:YES];

        [self.myTableView endUpdates];

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to iOS but for [sender tag] what do I put, I tried 'sender' which is what my button uses for a sender tag but it saids 'Expected identifier'

Comment: you did not do any thing just change type of your sender from `:(id)sender` to `:(UIButton*)sender` thats it.

Comment: sorry I don't understand, I changed [sender tag] to [sender]

Comment: still saids 'Expected identifier'

Comment: sorry dear my mistake there are extra brackets so its giving error please try update code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126493/discussion-between-dhanesh-and-brosimple).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126568/discussion-between-codechanger-and-brosimple).

Comment: whenever you can we can start the chat

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of convertPoint that you are using to get the indexPath of the clicked cell. Try creating a protocol in your CustomCell and implement your followButtonClick also in your CustomCell and use delegation to get the callBack in your controller with your CustomCell object and use that object to get the indexPath. Please refer the following code.

Your CustomCell.h
    #import

```
@protocol CustomCellDelegate;

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property(nonatomic,weak) id<CustomCellDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)followButtonClickedWithCell:(CustomCell *) cell;

@end
```

Your CustomCell.m

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell
...
-(void)followButtonClicked:(UIButton *) sender{
    if(self.delegate != nil){
        [self.delegate followButtonClickedWithCell:self];
    }
}

...
@end
```

Confirm your view controller to implement CustomCellDelegate and in the delegate method refer the following code to get the clicked indexPath

```
-(void)followButtonClickedWithCell:(CustomCell *) cell{
    NSIndexPath *clickedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    if (clickedIndexPath != nil){
        //Implement your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately the error does not end here. The deleting of the object works but now the inserting of the object to followedArray causes the crash. Updated the code.

Comment: Can you post the error that you had after trying this code?